# I am failing to override an admin phtml

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, adminhtml, overrides

I'm following the tutorial link below (first method), but I am not succeeding:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/admin/how_to_customize_backend_template_f.e._sales_order_information

I start creating my module on app/etc/modules/Fouron_Sales.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Fouron_Sales> 
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Fouron_Sales>
    </modules>
    <default>
        <blocks>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <sales_order_view_info>Mage_Fouron_Sales_Block_Sales_Order_View_Info</sales_order_view_info>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
        </blocks>
    </default>
</config>
```

After I created at app/code/local/Fouron/Sales/Block/Sales/Order/View/Info.php:

```
<?php

class Mage_Fouron_Sales_Block_Sales_Order_View_Info extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View_Info
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->setTemplate('fouron/sales/order/view/info.phtml');
    }     
}
```

And finally the file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/fouron/sales/order/view/info.phtml

I spend hours with this and tried some other modifications unsuccessfully, any help will be great. Thanks.

Comment: What is your Question?

Comment: My code isn't working and I don't found my error...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way to accomplish this since a lot of other paid module my customize this files, is to create a 
 [custom admin theme](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/admin/using_custom_admin_theme_templates)

In /app/etc/local.xml

```
 <stores>
    <admin>
        <design>
            <package>
                <name>default</name>
            </package>
            <theme>
                <default>fouron</default>
            </theme>
        </design>
    </admin>
</stores>
```

Then copy

> app/design/adminhtml/default/default/sales/order/view/info.phtml

to (and then make all your changes to this file)

> app/design/adminhtml/default/fouron/sales/order/view/info.phtml

Answer (score 1):

The `<default>` node is used for calls from `getStoreConfig`, not for setting rewrites:

**wrong:**

```
<default>
    <blocks>
        <adminhtml>
            <rewrite>
                <sales_order_view_info>Mage_Fouron_Sales_Block_Sales_Order_View_Info</sales_order_view_info>
            </rewrite>
        </adminhtml>
    </blocks>
</default>
```

**correct:**

```
<global>
    <blocks>
        <adminhtml>
            <rewrite>
                <sales_order_view_info>Mage_Fouron_Sales_Block_Sales_Order_View_Info</sales_order_view_info>
            </rewrite>
        </adminhtml>
    </blocks>
</global>
```

**Edit:**

Additionally, you should create your own namespace, e.g. `Fouron_MyModule` instead of `Mage_Fouron` so as to avoid confusion. Mage should be reserved for core modules only.

Even if you don't, however, your rewrite block is not located properly:

**Wrong:**

```
app/code/local/Fouron/Sales/Block/Sales/Order/View/Info.php
```

**Correct:**

```
app/code/local/Mage/Fouron/Sales/Block/Sales/Order/View/Info.php
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply philwinkle, but still not work:
http://i.stack.imgur.com/ikgy2.jpg

Comment: See my edit above.

Comment: I changed the folder and remove the Mage_ from Info.php and Fouron_Sales.xml... But now I am getting blank page... Maybe the setTemplate isn't finding info.phtml?

Comment: philwinkle the folder below is right, I only remove Mage_ from my files...
app/code/local/Fouron/Sales/Block/Sales/Order/View/Info.php

But now is not picking up the correct file, but this appeared right block ... I'm confused, please see the image below:
http://s16.postimg.org/3q7n2iq4l/erro.jpg

Comment: Is there a warning in magento system.log for a missing template file?

Comment: No, logs are empty.